# Google Sheets Printing Error when using Fixed Rows

Tags: google-sheets, printing

I have an employee who is trying to print a document in Google Sheets using Google Chrome. The first page prints correctly, but the additional pages only print the heading (created using Freeze Rows).

If she turns off Freeze Rows (either in the View Menu or in the Print Settings pop-up, it doesn't matter), the pages print correctly except that they are missing the headings.

If she brings up the spreadsheet in Microsoft Edge, it prints correctly with the Freeze Rows turned on, but this is a difficult solution because of everything we have set up in Chrome.

She has tried printing from multiple computers with the same result.

She was able to print the document successfully last week. Other, non-related documents seem to print just fine, even with Freeze Rows turned on.

To make this more complex, when I try to print the document in Chrome, it works fine. I have tried printing as another user (not an owner) and it prints fine.

I had her log into my PC to double check if it was the computer, and it still doesn't work for her, but it works for me. See the attached screen shot. Both logins are active and in the print settings screen, but one shows page two, and one doesn't. These two screens should show the exact same printouts.

[Screen Shot of both printing screens, Left shows 2nd page blank, right shows 2nd page okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j8YO.jpg)

Chrome is currently at the latest edition on her computer as well as on mine.

No one else in the company is having this issue. I have gone through her Chrome settings (nothing has changed) and can find nothing obvious.

I cannot submit the actual file for analysis because it contains payroll information and other sensitive material.

Thoughts?